# Webpack error when use custom definition types (types.d.ts) with Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, configuration, create-react-app

I want to write a custom definition types file in my React App, build with CRA, but when I start the app, there is an error :

> no extension
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> /home/rach/Documents/Code/BonApp/front-bon_app.ts/node_modules/myTypes
> doesn't exist
> .web.mjs

etc ...

But, the definition types file is just under `/src` and is correctly imported/found:

```js
declare module 'myTypes' {
  declare function someFunction(arg: number): void;
  export default someFunction;
}
```

my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/**/*", "src/types/**/*" , "test.d.ts"]
}
```

in `App.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

import User from 'adapters/primary/components/Molecules/User/User';

import './style/app.scss';
import someFunction from 'myTypes';

function App() {
  const test: void = someFunction(12);
  someFunction(13);
  console.log('-> testr', someFunction(14));
  return (
    <main>
      <User />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As I know, CRA is handling the `webpack.config.js` and we can't/ must not modify it.

So, how I can use my custom .d.ts please with a CRA ?

Thank you.

Grégory